# Unable to build EntityManagerFactory error (SPRING w/ HIBERNATE in JBOSS)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, jboss

There have been a alot of threads for this issue but I there was nothing that helped me. I tried to deploy this in **Tomcat 7** and it worked perfectly. Then I tried to deploy this in **JBOSS 6.4** and got this error below.

**ERROR**

```
"failure-description" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"TaskManagementSystem.war#persistenceUnit\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"TaskManagementSystem.war#persistenceUnit\": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: persistenceUnit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: persistenceUnit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Connection cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set"}},
"rolled-back" => true
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">

<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>com.project.taskmanagement.model.User</class>
    <class>com.project.taskmanagement.model.UserProfile</class>
    <class>com.project.taskmanagement.model.Role</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<!-- DataSource -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}"></property>
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}"></property>
    <property name="username" value="${database.user}"></property>
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}"></property>
</bean>

<!-- EntityManager -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:/META-INF/persistence.xml" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
         <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="${hibernate.show_sql}" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="${hibernate.generate_ddl}" />
         </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <!-- <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">0</prop> -->
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- TransactionManager -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

**Versions I used in pom.xml**

```
    <spring.version>4.3.9.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.security.version>4.2.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.11.Final</hibernate.version>
    <mysql.version>5.1.38</mysql.version>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <servlet-api.version>3.1.0</servlet-api.version>
    <persistence-api.version>1.0.2</persistence-api.version>
    <jsp.version>2.2</jsp.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <tiles.version>3.0.7</tiles.version>
```

**UPDATE:**
Tried this in JBOSS 7.0 and it's working fine. But the requirement is to use JBOSS 6.4 so I still need to work on this one. Could someone please explain why am I getting this error? Thank you!

Comment: Try to specify @EnableTransactionManagement

Comment: @Reborn Could you elaborate what you mean by that?

Comment: There is no close tag for persistence in persistence.xml in the last line `</persistence>`. I think that's the reason persistence.xml file is not parsed correctly and the properties are not detected.

Comment: @yaswanth, done updating it.

Comment: @Makudex is that a typo in the question or you didn't have the close tag in your code?

Comment: @yaswanth typo.